# Splash Screen Size in PhoneGap App

Tags: android, phonegap-build, splash-screen

I am trying to set a width and a height for my splash screen in my *config.xml*.

I am using *PhoneGap Build* and the PhoneGap version is *3.7.0*, and the target is *Andoird*.

The splash screen always shows up very distorted (i.e. it will always be resized so it fits the entire screen).

The following has no effect:

```
<gap:splash src="./assets/img/logos/appLogo.png" width='200' height='100' />
```

And the following does not make the splash screen show at all:

```
<gap:splash src="./assets/img/logos/appLogo.png" gap:platform="android"  width='200' height='100' />
```

Answer (score 2):

You should provide different splashscreens for different screen sizes.

According to the phonegap wiki ( https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Splash-Screen-Sizes ) the sizes should be:

```
LDPI:
Portrait: 200x320px
Landscape: 320x200px
MDPI:
Portrait: 320x480px
Landscape: 480x320px
HDPI:
Portrait: 480x800px
Landscape: 800x480px
XHDPI:
Portrait: 720px1280px
Landscape: 1280x720px
XXHDPI:
Portrait: 960px1600px
Landscape: 1600x960px
XXXHDPI:
Portrait: 1280px1920px
Landscape: 1920x1280px
```

You can point in your config.xml to the splashscreens you provide, for example:

```
<gap:splash src="res/screen/splash_ldpi.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/splash_mdpi.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/splash_hdpi.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/splash_xhdpi.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
```

Comment: Hi, I need to add new splash for 1080x2340 redmi note 8 and similar phones. What is the configuration?