# What is the default Android Splashcreen size used for PhoneGap

Tags: android, phonegap-build, phonegap

I have found the required SplashScreen sizes required for Android here https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Splash-Screen-Sizes

Can anybody tell me what the **default** SplashScreen size is, as required by PhoneGap.

Comment: This link might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33567481/splash-screen-size-in-phonegap-app

Comment: Hi, I do use all the various Splashscreen sizes required but there is a default SplashScreen required and I'm wondering if this is just a generic size or is there a recomended size. I use 720x960 pixels.